# Apache 2.2.17 not returning last modified date of https static file

Tags: apache, http-headers, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm using NSurlconnect and an NSurlrequest to get the http headers from a static txt file served from an apache server but it does not return the last modified date.

What Apache server configuration directive would prevent this or what could i have the server guys add to the configuration to enable this to show.

FYI I have tried other urls on different servers and i am able to get last-modified from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with certificates and the solution was to revise the allowable canAuthentiateAgainstProtectionSpace options.

It caused me some confusion because I received a response and it allowed me to download the file even though the response was a http 401 response.  once I fixed the authenificiation problem i started to get the correct   304 and 200 options back from the server along with all the expected headers

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question but I think that the reason the header is not stowing last=modified is that there are .htaccess files somewhere in the configuration of the server that specify

Header unset last-Modified

or that some other mod or apache2.cnf has some other directive..

if anyone knows better please  advise.